# How to save events in database with fullcalendar v4

Tags: fullcalendar

Before, I'm used Ajax to save events and it was ok. But now, with the v4, my code doesn't work anymore like if Ajax doesn't recognise anymore. Does someone have the solution ?

My code in v3.09

```
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) { // Déplacement d'une événement
    var date = new Date();
    if (($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "M")>=date.getMonth()+1 && $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "D")>=date.getDate()) || ($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "M")>date.getMonth()+1)) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/update_events.php',
            data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") +'&end='+ $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") +'&id='+ event.id ,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(json) {
                $('#script-info').show();
                setTimeout('divOff()',1000);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert ("Vous ne pouvez pas déplacer une absence à une date antérieure à la date du jour.");
        revertFunc();
    }
},
```

My code in v4

```
eventDrop: function(info) {
    var date = new Date();

    if (calendar.formatDate(info.event.start, {month: 'numeric'})>=date.getMonth()+1 && calendar.formatDate(info.event.start, {day: 'numeric'})>=date.getDate()) {
         $.ajax({
            url: 'php/update_events.php',
            data: 'title="Test"',
            type: "POST",
            success: function(json) {
                $('#script-info').show();
                setTimeout('divOff()',1000);
            }
        });
    alert('Ok');
    } else {
        alert('Vous ne pouvez pas déplacer un créneau de sport à une date antérieure à la date du jour.');
        info.revert();
    }
}
```

Comment: You didn't mention exactly _how_ it's "not working" - in future a description of an actual error or unexpected behaviour would be a lot more useful to people trying to help you. But in this case I can guess your issue. There's still an eventDrop function, but its signature is different - it delivers all the data in a single object with various properties for the different parts. Try reading the v4 manual: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventDrop and you should see it's fairly obvious that the structure has changed. Your code will need to change to read the right data from the new object.

Comment: In fact, nothing append like if Ajax didn't compatible with this version. It's not a question of structure but directly Ajax. I try most of things in the part of code's ajax. I have the same problem with all ajax's part not only with eventDrop

Comment: please show what you tried to make it compatible with the new version. Because I can't see any evidence of whether you got it right or not. And if you say the problem is "directly with ajax" then please tell me exactly what the problem is. Do you get an error message? Or strange response from the server? Or something else? I can't help you if you don't tell me the the precise issue. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. One thing to note is that v4 doesn't require jQuery any more. So if you have also removed jQuery from your page, then $.ajax() will not work because that's a jQuery function. You should have an error in your browser's console about it. You'd have to use the native XMLHttpRequest object, or alternatively some other AJAX wrapper library such as axios or superagent, or you could just re-include jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But as I said earlier "doesn't work" is not a sufficient description of the problem. Please open your browser's Developer Tools and check for errors either in the Console, or in the Network tools (relating specifically to the ajax call going to update_events.php). You could also try using the JavaScript debugger to step through your code and see what paths it is taking and what values your variables have got, and see if you can see some unexpected behaviour. In other words, you need to debug your code!

Comment: You give me the solution ! I've removed <script src='lib/jquery.min.js'></script>. How stupid i am ! So, it's works again. Sorry for the inconvenient

Answer (score 0):

You give me the solution !
I've removed script src='lib/jquery.min.js' script.

How stupid i am ! So, it's works again. Sorry for the inconvenient

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps others, but if you want to save events via ajax in V4 this is what I did assuming calEvent is coming from sort of event (click, drag etc) in V4:

```
eventClick: function (calEvent) {  var cloned= jQuery.extend(true, {},calendar.getEventById( calEvent.event.id ));
cloned.start=clientEvents[i].start;
cloned.end=clientEvents[i].end;
cloned.title=clientEvents[i].title
delete cloned.jsEvent;
delete cloned.view;
```

Above shows how you can clone the event (needs jquery) and then add custom properties, remove some unneeded properties and ultimately turn this into JSON to send back to server.

HTH